# segmenting lat/long data graph into lines/vectors

Tags: r, math

I have lat/lng data of multirotor UAV flights. There are alot of datapoints (~13k per flight) and I wish to find line segments from the data. They give me flight speed and direction. I know that most of the flights are guided missons meaning a point is given to fly to. However the exact points are unknown to me.

Here is a graph of a single flight lat/lng shifted to near (0,0) so they are visible on the same time-series graph.

[image]

I attempted to generate similar data, but there are several constraints and it may take more time to solve than working on the segmenting.

- The graphs start and end nearly always at the same point.
- Horisontal lines mean the UAV is stationary. These segments are expected.
- Beginning and and end are always stationary for takeoff and landing.
- There is some level of noise in the lines for the gps accuracy tho seemingly not that much.
- Alot of data points.
- The number of segments is unknown.

The noise I could calculate given the segments and least squares method to the line. Currently I'm thinking of sampling the data (to decimate it a little) and constructing lines. Merging the lines with smaller angle than x (dependant on the noise) and finding the intersection points of the lines left.

Another thought is to try and look at this problem in the frequency domain. The corners should be quite high frequency. Maybe I could make a custom filter kernel that would enable me to use a window function and win in efficency.

EDIT: Rewrote the question for more clarity and less rambling.

Comment: How many line segments do you want in total? The minimum to retain the same shape would be 6.

Comment: As an ML practitioner, you should know that garbage in means garbage out. You've posted a 200 word question and I can't figure out what the question is. Imagine you knew the solution - now try to teach us the problem so that we come ourselves to that solution.

Comment: Can you include a minimal working example in your question please? Seems like one approach would be to calculate slopes between sequential points and group them accordingly. I'm not sure why you need to do any fitting.

Comment: Sorry, I will rebuild the question when I'm back home, which is on friday. After thinking about the problem further I see I have omitted important bits of information.

Comment: I think it would still be useful for you to provide some sample data. That said, consider the Ramer–Douglas–Peucker algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm), implemented in `rgeos::gSimplify` (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rgeos/versions/0.3-26/topics/gSimplify).